Mismatched associated types, but the types are the same
I'm looking for help on the following error that I recently stumbled upon and I'm unable to solve.
pub trait Datatype: Display + Default + Clone + 'static {
    type ParseError: Display + Clone + 'static;

    fn parse<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) -> Result<Self, Self::ParseError>;
}

pub trait Validate: Datatype {
    type Inner: Datatype;
    type ValidateError: Default + Clone + Display + 'static;

    fn validate(input: Self::Inner) -> Result<Self, <Self as Validate>::ValidateError> where Self: Sized;
}

impl<T> Datatype for T
where
    T: Validate,
    T::Inner: Datatype,
{
    type ParseError = T::ValidateError;

    fn parse<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) -> Result<T, Self::ParseError> {
        T::Inner::parse(input)
            .map_err(|_| T::ValidateError::default())
            .and_then(T::validate)
    }
}


The compiler gives me the following error at the implementation for the parse function:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:24:9
   |
23 |       fn parse<S: AsRef<str>>(input: S) -> Result<T, Self::ParseError> {
   |                                            --------------------------- expected `Result<T, <T as Datatype>::ParseError>` because of return type
24 | /         T::Inner::parse(input)
25 | |             .map_err(|_| T::ValidateError::default())
26 | |             .and_then(T::validate)
   | |__________________________________^ expected `Datatype::ParseError`, found `Validate::ValidateError`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<_, <T as Datatype>::ParseError>`
              found enum `Result<_, <T as Validate>::ValidateError>`

Obviously, I have set the type ParseError to be the same as the ValidateError, so the types should be the same. If someone could explain what's going on there, or even provide a fix, I'd be very thankful!
Playground

I was able to make it compile - playground - but not really pleased about it. Sometimes introducing another generic E and using that to constrain everything makes it easier for the compiler to see that E == E, but your code was awkward in the first place cuz of the chicken-and-egg implementation.

This is likely a bug, the compiler emits the same TypeId for both types: Playground, It should be able to prove both are the same type, it just somehow can't.

Yeah I think this falls into the case of Rust being overly conservative and rejecting valid programs. This could probably be fixed later, but at least there is a fairly trivial workaround that works on stable.

Rust is confused by the recursive dependency. You require that Validate: Datatype, but then try to implement Datatype for any T that is Validate. If you remove the requirement that Validate: Datatype and instead require Validate: Display + Default + Clone + 'static everything works fine.

Hmm this works, but then I can't do something like
fn test<V: Validate>(v: V) { v.parse("test").unwrap(); }
Now there is a problem that the compiler doesn't know for sure whether datatype is implemented for validate.

@FabianBösiger That shouldn't happen as long as it can see the blanket implementation.

You're right, thanks for the help!
